# How to read arabic text contents from an excel sheet in BluePrism?

Tags: excel, blueprism, arabic-support

I am new to BluePrism and trying to read Arabic from an Excel sheet. But when I open collection process it shows question marks instead of showing Arabic characters. I tried to write this data into another sheet but it prints the same question mark rather Arabic.

[image: Collection Screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure if BP supports Arabic. Can you describe exactly what do you want to achieve? Move text between Excel Sheets?

Comment: I want to take this arabic text and will login an application in browser and save there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the `Get Cell Value` command and that worked well with Arabic, which lead me to believe the problem isn't with Blue Prism as a whole, but only in the way the `Get Range Collection` is built.

If you have a look at the VB.NET code behind the action, you see that the BP developers first copy the range into clipboard and then parse the clipboard contents into the collection. That's where the problem most likely occurs.

A quick workaround would be not using the `Get Range as Collection` at all and use just the `Get Cell Value` instead, longer workaround would be modifying the `Get Range as Collection` action.

I can see two options for the longer workaround as well. Either you figure out the problem with the way the clipboard parsing works and fix it, or you change the logic to fill the DataTable directly (for each row and for each column set cell value to Table). The performance will be worse, but it will work).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to install the Font on your machine and get the Worksheet as a collection. Or maybe Translate all in English, get it and then translate it in Arabic Again, Or maybe read cell by cell if entire collection isn't working.
It would be helpful to have the worksheet as example.